# Oracle nested multiple subqueries

Tags: oracle, subquery, nested

I am looking for a reliable algorithmic way to nest queries in Oracle without having to parse and rebuild SQL statements. In DB2, MYSQL, and SQLITE I can simply nest from the largest columns set in the inner subquery to the smallest column set in the very outer query like this:

```
  SELECT A, B FROM (
       SELECT A, B, C FROM (
            SELECT A, B, C, D FROM (
                 SELECT * FROM myTable
                 )
            )
      )
 )
```

This does not work for Oracle, I had to use the WITH clause but that allows me one level of nesting like

```
 WITH Q1 as (
      SELECT * FROM myTable 
            ) 
            SELECT A, B FROM Q1
```

is there an algorithmic way to nest select statements in Oracle like DB2 or MySQL above

You can always assume it is a single table. The queries are generated automatically

Found the root cause:

My code assumes an "AS alias" is needed and appends it to the subquery as in "Select A, B from (select A, B, C from myTable) **AS Q1**"      --- Oracle does not like that and gives an error  "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: You have one-too-many right parentheses in the code you posted (four rights but only three lefts).  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "does not work"?  The structure you seem to want works perfectly well in Oracle

```
SQL> select ename from (
  2    select ename, empno from (
  3      select ename, empno, job from (
  4        select ename, empno, job, mgr from (
  5          select * from emp
  6        )
  7      )
  8    )
  9  );

ENAME
----------
SMITH
ALLEN
WARD
JONES
MARTIN
BLAKE
CLARK
SCOTT
KING
TURNER
ADAMS
JAMES
FORD
MILLER

14 rows selected.
```

Comment: If I was wrong (and I hope I am) then my code failed on the Oracle wrapper only and I am investigating why.  Thank you in advance.